# Ubuntu server can't send GET request on one particular ip address

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have a droplet from DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64).

When I tried to send GET request through `ruby open-uri` from the server, it gets timeout for one particular ip address, and it works well for all other ip address.

```
irb(main):001:0> open("https://www.google.ca/")
=> #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri20191121-3549-1dtt546>     // works
irb(main):002:0> open("https://stackoverflow.com/")
=> #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri20191121-3549-3j1xyi>      // works
irb(main):003:0> open("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/") // doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from (irb):3
       15: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
       14: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'
       13: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
       12: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
       11: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
       10: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
        9: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'
        8: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:337:in `open_http'
        7: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
        6: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
        5: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
        4: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        3: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `block in connect'
        2: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `open'
        1: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `initialize'
Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)
irb(main):004:0> open("https://130.14.29.110/") // 130.14.29.110 is the ip of www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from (irb):4
       15: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
       14: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'
       13: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
       12: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
       11: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
       10: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
        9: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'
        8: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:337:in `open_http'
        7: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
        6: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
        5: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
        4: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        3: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `block in connect'
        2: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `open'
        1: from /apps/orth/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `initialize'
Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)
```

Here is `traceroute` output on www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov

```
traceroute to www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (130.14.29.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  159.89.176.253 (159.89.176.253)  1.315 ms  1.266 ms  1.265 ms
 2  138.197.248.26 (138.197.248.26)  0.800 ms 138.197.248.8 (138.197.248.8)  0.765 ms  9.825 ms
 3  138.197.244.26 (138.197.244.26)  0.899 ms 138.197.244.16 (138.197.244.16)  0.865 ms 138.197.244.30 (138.197.244.30)  1.593 ms
 4  * * *
 5  ae-1-3501.ear2.Washington1.Level3.net (4.69.206.69)  7.459 ms  7.096 ms  7.189 ms
 6  NATIONAL-LI.ear2.Washington1.Level3.net (4.59.144.190)  7.075 ms  6.621 ms  6.586 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Here is my `ufw` setting

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I asked the NCBI support, and they said they didn't block my ip address or put my ip address in their blacklist. So, I am thinking there is something wrong with my server.

May I ask how could I make the diagnosis on the problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: So is it not reachable with e.g. `curl` either?

Comment: Hi @TomYan, Yes, I can't curl https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ either.